# What does l "be taped-off" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have come across it in this news [article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-53373132).

> The protests were not authorised and in Khabarovsk the meeting point
> had been **taped-off** overnight, supposedly for Covid 19 disinfection.
> But the crowds marched in any case, and the police - on this occasion
> didn't intervene.

I would like also know whether it was used as an adjective or phrasal verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the coloured plastic tape which is stretched between metal posts to indicate that an area is temporarily 'out of bounds' to the public, for instance to keep people away from a crime scene under investigation, or to keep those watching an outdoor event out of the way of the participants. I would say it's a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 1):

"To tape off" means to mark with tape — typically not with adhesive tape, but with [yellow caution tape](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DUY93XC).

It's a phrasal verb; the hyphen is an error.